# Looking for a Transcription Program

Tags: windows, music

I am looking for a transcription program that will receive an audio file (.mp3) and will print out the music sheet.

I don't mind the cost, and I am using Windows.

I don't think there are anything else to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [IntelliScore](http://www.intelliscore.net/faq.html):

- non-free but trial is available
- multi-instrument, multi-drum audio to notation converter
- supports CD, WAV, MP3, AAC, AIFF or WMA
- [transcription demo](http://www.intelliscore.net/download.html)
- once you get the MIDI you can use a [program to convert a MIDI file into music sheets](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4514/903).

[image]