# Program to convert a MIDI file into music sheets

Tags: music, midi, music-sheet

I'm looking for a program that can convert a MIDI file into music sheets.

If possible:

- Free
- Windows 7

Comment: Question asking for a Linux software: [MIDI to music sheet converter for Linux](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/34204/60)

Comment: @unor Thanks, also I think the question also requires CLI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Midi Sheet Music](http://midisheetmusic.sourceforge.net/)

- free and open source
- plays MIDI music files while highlighting the piano notes and sheet music notes
- supports multiple channels
- Works on Windows, Mac OS X, and Ubuntu Linux.
- Export the sheets to PDF

[image]