# Open source Python library for Automatic Music Transcription

Tags: audio, artificial-intelligence

I produced several songs with voice and piano or guitar chords. I am looking for software, ideally open source in Python, that takes a WAV or MP3 file and produces a MIDI file, which I can then convert to sheet music. I am OK with [70% accuracy](http://akoff.com/audio-to-midi.html), as I can produce the voice and instrument tracks independently and clean up afterwards. My question is similar to [Looking for a Transcription Program](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4506/looking-for-a-transcription-program) but for macOS and ideally open-source. I believe the recent progress in neural networks would have made significant impact in this field.

I found [OmniZart](https://pypi.org/project/omnizart/) and was taken aback that the linked homepage is in Chinese, and [AnthemScore and ScoreCloud](https://windowsreport.com/automatically-transcribe-music/) that run on macOS.

What automatic music transcription software do you recommend?